# Paste before multiline selection

Tags: vim

I have some prefix in yank buffer that I want to paste in multiple lines before the area selected by visual-block selection.

When I press `I` I can start typing text before selection in each line but when I try to paste (using either `p` or `P`) it changes selection with pasted text. How to avoid removing selected text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to expand your yanked text during insertion. If you have just yanked "word" (so that it is in the register `"0`), then you could do `i<ctrl-r>0<esc>`. This is exactly like typing `i` or `I`, except that you place the content of your yanked text (in this case, the contents of register `0`) in your inserted text.